# Dockerized Python Scripts Having Issues Accessing Files Stored to /tmp

Tags: python, django, docker, celery, spacy

I want to apologize in advance that I don't have specific code examples to share (though I have included my docker-compose file below that may or may not be helpful). I am having a strange issue I can't seem to trace and I am not 100% sure what to share.

I have a django + celery setup running in Docker (based off of cookiecutter-django). Everything seems to be working great at first. I have extensively tested and used this setup *outside* of Docker, and the Dockerized Celery tasks generally behave as I'd expect (i.e., as they did when they were not Dockerized).

Here's where things get weird, though. For various reasons, I need to load some data files and create temp files at runtime that I can't just put in my docker file. One example is Using NamedTemporaryFile. Another is installing the data files from [Spacy](https://spacy.io/usage/models). In both cases, my scripts are storing data to /tmp (I know the easy answer here is to put them in my docker file, but I can't predict which files I need ahead of time, sadly). When my celery task worker tries to access data files it supposedly created, downloaded, and/or stored to /tmp, I keep getting file not found errors. Weird thing is I don't get any errors in my logs that file creation or downloads failed...

Yet, when I /bin/bash into my celeryworker container and cd to the /tmp directory, sure enough, no files are there... If, using the python console in my container, I run the *same* code, I have no issues and the files do show up in /tmp. I'm not getting a consistent error message and the behavior is manifesting itself differently in different scripts, so it's hard to give you a specific error message / stack trace. The common element appears to stem from some issue that arises when my celery task tries to dynamically store data in /tmp and then access it immediately after that. I'm a Docker newb and am at a loss as to what to do next. I suspect this may be a permissioning issue, but I've tried chmodding /tmp to 777 and it didn't fix anything. I also thought it might be a volume issue, but, if that's the case, I wasn't sure why I can make everything work if I use bash inside my container.

Anyone have any advice here? Spent a couple of days trying to trace the source of the issue at this point and am at a dead end. My docker file and configs are pretty much plain vanilla copies of Django Cookiecutter defaults.

```
version: '3'

volumes:
  local_postgres_data: {}
  local_postgres_data_backups: {}

services:
  django: &django
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/local/django/Dockerfile
    image: gremlin_gplv3_local_django
    container_name: django
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - tika
      - redis
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    env_file:
      - ./.envs/.local/.django
      - ./.envs/.local/.postgres
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    command: /start

  postgres:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/production/postgres/Dockerfile
    image: gremlin_gplv3_production_postgres
    container_name: postgres
    volumes:
      - local_postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - local_postgres_data_backups:/backups
    env_file:
      - ./.envs/.local/.postgres

  redis:
    image: redis:5.0
    container_name: redis

  celeryworker:
    <<: *django
    image: gremlin_gplv3_local_celeryworker
    container_name: celeryworker
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - postgres

    ports: []
    command: /start-celeryworker

  celerybeat:
    <<: *django
    image: gremlin_gplv3_local_celerybeat
    container_name: celerybeat
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - postgres

    ports: []
    command: /start-celerybeat

  flower:
    <<: *django
    image: gremlin_gplv3_local_flower
    container_name: flower
    ports:
      - "5555:5555"
    command: /start-flower

  tika:
    image: lexpredict/tika-server
    command: /start-tika
```

Comment: You are aware that every Docker container has its own file system with its own tmp directory?

Comment: @Klaus, yes, I am, though perhaps I'm misunderstanding something about what that means. In my setup celeryworker has its own /tmp, right? And this is separate from all the other containers' /tmp? So if my celeryworker runs an install script or writes to its /tmp, then it should be able to see the /tmp files though no other container can? I've been /bin/bashing in to celeryworker's container, assuming I'm then using the same env as my celeryworker code. Let me know if I'm misunderstanding something. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured this out... well, mostly. The problem is Spacy (and other, similar libraries and tools that download data files) put them into local directories on their file system and possibly create symlinks to them). In a docker container, however, these files and symlinks are not persistent, however, unless the parent directory is in a docker volume.

What I ended up doing is creating docker volumes for the folder that Spacy (or whatever library) uses to store data files / libraries. In my case, Spacy is always called from via Celery which has its own docker image in my docker-compose stack, so I needed to attach volumes for each of my Spacy data directories to my celeryworker like so:

```
version: '3'

volumes:
  local_postgres_data: {}
  local_postgres_data_backups: {}
  worker_usr: {}
  worker_root: {}
  worker_tmp: {}

services:
  
  [...]

  celeryworker:
    <<: *django
    image: local_django:latest
    container_name: celeryworker
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - postgres
    volumes:
      - worker_usr:/usr
      - worker_tmp:/tmp
      - worker_root:/root
      - .:/app

    ports: []
    command: /start-celeryworker
```

All of this said, I've noticed there are situations where, at first pass, the installation of a data file (like a Spacy model) in my worker container throws an error that the data file is still not accessible, yet, when this happens (and it's not all the time), I can just run the install again and 99% of the time, this appears to fix the issue. I have not had time to try to troubleshoot that. Perhaps someone else can figure that part out.